# Can't install the app, because of connection refused?

Tags: shopware

I am trying to develop an app for shopware6, I already added the containers and stuff on docker-compose file same as it is explained on [documentation](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/apps/local-development/app-development-with-docker), but now when I try to install and activate the app it shows me an error

````
In AppRegistrationService.php line 78:

  cURL error 7: Failed to connect to localhost port 7777: Connection refused (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for http://localhost:7777/registration?shop-id=D9YCMIDjZ9nxnoJf&sho
  p-url=http://shopware&timestamp=1629271484```


In CurlFactory.php line 210:

  cURL error 7: Failed to connect to localhost port 7777: Connection refused (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for http://localhost:7777/registration?shop-id=D9YCMIDjZ9nxnoJf&sho
  p-url=http://shopware&timestamp=1629271484
````

I am using the [AppExample template](https://github.com/shopwareLabs/AppExample/), from the official documentation of shopware

Comment: This internal Shop port seems to be 8000, while the port exposed via docker is 7777. So maybe you APP_URL uses port 7777 and should use 8000 ?

Comment: Did you find a solution? Did that help?

Comment: Yes I did, in case you need to render the app as iframe on shopware you have to access via localhost:7777 url but for intern communication you have to write the app container name in my case it was http://example, so in my case the registration url was <registrationUrl>http://example/registration</registrationUrl>

Answer (score 0):

This internal Shop port seems is 8000, while the port exposed via docker is 7777. So the App can be accessed via port 7777 i.e. `http://localhost:7777/`